# assigning a value to a variable with certain probability

Tags: java, probability

I have written a function in the following way:

```
public static double acceptance(double E1, double E2, int t) {
      return exp((E1 - E2) / t);   
}
```

Suppose now I want to assign a value into a variable `x` with a probability `exp((E1-E2)/t)`.

so, for doing this what will I have to do? If write in the following way:

```
if(acceptance(double E1, double E2, int t) > Math.random())  // E1,E2 and t have certain values
    x = value;
```

will it be right or will I have to make any change?

Comment: do you familiar with actual method parameters?

Comment: Your second code fragment is not syntactically correct.  Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work, if Math.random() is always in the range 0-1.
However I would switch the values to make it more readable. E.g.:

```
if(Math.random() < acceptance(...)) {...}
```

Comment: Math.random() can produce 0 as output. if acceptance is also 0 your boolean statement would be true. But since 0 should mean 0% chance it shouldn't. Therefor using "<=" seems wrong and should be switched to "<" (As in original code)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that should be "<" rather than ">", assuming E1, E2 and t are always going to give you exp((E1 - E2)/t) in the range [0.0, 1.0)

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the higher "acceptance" is, the lower the probability the value will be set? Doesn't seem right to me.